# How to load 64-bit ActiveX control in 64-bit IE version 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I am trying to figure out how to load 64-bit ActiveX control in 64-bit IE version 11 on Windows 8.1.

This is what I did/tried already:

- Changed UAC setting
- Turned 'Enable 64-bit process for Enhanced Protected Mode*' and 'Enable Enhanced Protected Mode*' on in IE settings
- Registered 64-bit ActiveX control as one that is compatible with AppContainer

When I launch IE with just Google.com in a single tab, the Task Manger is showing both the main process and the tab process as 64-bit process which is expected. But when I open HTML file containing 64-bit OCX integration I get the message box 'Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls'. When I click on 'Allow blocked content' there is nothing on the screen. The Task Manager is showing that newly created tab process is 32-bit.

If I set HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\TabProcGrowth to 0 then 64-bit ActiveX content is loaded IE 11 and everything works just fine.

I can repro this issue with 64-bit hhctrl.ocx used in HTML Help Workshop

This is the simple HTML test file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">

<HTML>

<HEAD>

<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft&reg; HTML Help Workshop 4.1">

<Title>TestOCX</Title>

</HEAD>

<BODY>

<OBJECT id=hhctrl type="application/x-oleobject"

        classid="clsid:adb880a6-d8ff-11cf-9377-00aa003b7a11"

        codebase="hhctrl.ocx#Version=6,3,9600,18006"

        width=100

        height=100

>

    <PARAM name="Command" value="HH Version">

    <PARAM name="Button" value="Text:Version">

</OBJECT>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

If this HTML file is loaded in 64-bit IE the newly created process is 32-bit for some reason and embedded OCX cannot be loaded.

This issue can be reproduced using Microsoft Tabular Data Control (TDC) ActiveX control ([TDC control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: From IE select the File>Properties menu to find out which IE Security zone your test site/domain maps to... expected 'intranet'. By default intranet sites use 32bit tab processes. Your company computers are bound to have a mixture of 32bit and 64bit machines so you should deploy both x86 and x64 versions of your control.

Comment: This is what I see in File->Properties... Zone: My Computer | Protected Mode: Off. If x86 version of OCX is registered the 32-bit IE process will use it but what I need to find out is how to have the 64-bit IE tab that loads 64-bit OCX.

Comment: I see the same problem with 2 Microsoft ActveX controls: hhctrl.ocx and tdc.ocx. 64-bit version of both controls load fine in IE if TabProcGrowth registry setting is set to 0. But if that setting is not 0 the IE tab created is 32-bit and 64-bit controls are not loaded.